# Region on Complex Plane Without Modulus

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I am doing a homework about sketching regions of complex numbers on the Gaussian plane, and I am stuck at this situation;

$${\{z \in \mathbb{C}\,\, |\, Re(z)+Im(z) = 3\, \lor |z-2-2i|=3\}}$$

I know that if the modulus of a complex number equals a number, then we should draw a circle (Just like the second part of the statement)... But I am facing a problem with the left hand side of the OR statement. Is it supposed to be a circle too, even if there's no modulus? If it was a product, then the result will be the intersection of the lines $Im(z)=3$ and $Re(z)=3$.

Comment: $z=x+iy \Rightarrow x+y=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, $\operatorname{Re}(z)+\operatorname{Im}z=3$ is just the line $x+y=3$. And $|z-2-2i|=3$ is just the circle with center $(2,2)$ and radius $3$. So, you have the union of a line and a circle.